# Can I define a DBIx::Class::ResultSource::View after connecting?

Tags: postgresql, perl, sqlite, dbi, dbix-class

I have a virtual table in DBIx::Class whose definition needs to differ depending on the deployment. If I deploy against sqlite3 I can use `group_concat` but when I deploy on Postgres I need to use `string_agg` in the definition that I then use in

```
__PACKAGE__->result_source_instance->view_definition($sql);
```

Is there a way to do it depending on the connection?

Comment: Can you add an example ::View with the two different values that you need to use? I think I have an idea of how to do that, but I'm not firm enough with my DBIC to set it up myself.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/simonecesano/568ed87082914c1c25fa881cdcca8bfc and https://gist.github.com/simonecesano/50da29e94de4301bba789ed1bbdfa7ec I hope it helps. The SQL might not work in practice, I might have mangled it too badly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could exclude the view from deployment, add the ddl sql in your schema class depending on the database you're connected to and not define it as a virtual view in which case the sql in the result class isn't used for anything.